# PHP - How to populate database data on a page with pagination

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a database with tables that has data with about 5 columns. I need to get this data on the webpage that includes a pagination (page will include 5 items). I think I figured out the pagination part but I dont know how to get all the data from the database and create each item. You can see my mockup [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d27hG.png).

How can I possibly do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have 5 column as id, uname, fname, lname, age in user table. You can use this:

```
$i = 0; // Start from row $i
$j = 10; // Number of rows you want
$connection = mysqli_connect("your_server","User_name","Password","db");
$stmt = $connection->prepare('
  SELECT
    id, uname, fname, lname, age
  FROM
    user
  LIMIT
    ?, ?
');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $i, $j);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $uname, $fname, $lname, $age);
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $result = array(); 
  do {
    array_push($result, array(
      'id' => $id,
      'uname' => $uname,
      'fname' => $fname,
      'lname' => $lname,
      'age' => $age
    ));
  while ($stmt->fetch());
} else {
  // no rows fetched
}
```

After that for use data you can do like this:

```
foreach ($result as $r) {
  echo $r['id'].$r['uname'].$r['fname'].$r['lname'].$r['age'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you'll need something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    yourtable
WHERE
    somecol = somevalue
LIMIT
    start, results
```

Where start is the starting number, and results the number of results per page.

Comment: What do you mean by starting number? I have 5 columns in the table with like 20-30 rows. I need to get this data populated like the image I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom you have used 1,2,3....n.  Use this number as a button form which will submit:

1. for 01
2. for 06
3. for 11
   .........
   n. for n*5+1

```
<form action="form.php" method="post"> 
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="1">1</button>
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="6">2</button>
</form>
//At form.php add the below code
$status=$_POST['subject']; 
$i=1;
////////////////////////Database connection start
$con = mysql_connect('MySQL host name ', 'username', 'password');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('Database_name', $con);
$sql="set names 'utf8'";// for unicode support, must use after mysql_select_db() function.
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')or die('charset problem:'.mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'") 
or die('collation      problem:'.mysql_error());
////////////////////////Database connection ends
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE status='$status'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['email'];
    if(i==6) break;
}
```